# Menu isn´t responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, nav

I want to make my menu responsive and the button that opens responsive nav will be hidden in "desktop mode" and I found some info on w3school, but I probably made an error. Can you help me with that please? Thanks very much! I am a begginer coder. 
If I tried to make the navigation responsive I edited the CSS code and it made the navigation not hidden and the responsive button is showing.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 65px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: block
}

.dropbtn:hover~.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-right a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-right a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-right.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .header-right.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a id="txt" hidden></a>
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6Nkbdb3/dlhemenu-1-1-1.png" class="logo" title="logo webstránky MENU - www.menu-web.eu" alt="MENU logo" width="150" height="50" onClick="window.location.reload();"> &nbsp
  <a class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp</i>test<?php echo $_SESSION['meno']; ?> 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">

    <a href="ucet.php">Môj účet</a>
    <a href="logout.php">Odhlásiť sa</a>

  </div>



  <div class="header-right" id="myTopnav">
    <a class="active" href="/welcome.php">Úvodné menu</a>
    <a href="/online.php">Online hodiny</a>
    <a href="/du.php">Domáce úlohy</a>
    <a href="webcentrum/znamky">Známky</a>
    <a href="/rozvrh.php">Rozvrh hodín</a>
    <a href="/ospravedlnenky.php">Ospravedlnenky</a>
    <a href="/ucenie.php">Učebný materiál</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As a side note, you should start using semantic tags. Then use `classList.toggle` in your JS. Last but not least, do not use `float` outside of its intended purpose (floating an element within a text-block). It should not be sued for aligning purposes. I know that w3school unfortunately teaches such outdated methods (outdated since 2012 or 2015 depending on which marks you look at).  The main reasons why most seniors do not recommend using w3school for the web stack without supervision. It is hard to recognize as a beginner which of their topics are outdated or bad use.

Comment: Where is `#myTopnav` in u code?

Comment: @AndreiFedorov I added this, I have added it my code, but I don´t put it on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I read the mistake details carefully.
Please, Try the code following.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.header a.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .header-right {
    float: none;
  }
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 65px;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: block
}

.dropbtn:hover~.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-right a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .header-right a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header-right.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .header-right.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <a id="txt" class="hidden"></a>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6Nkbdb3/dlhemenu-1-1-1.png" class="logo" title="logo webstránky MENU - www.menu-web.eu" alt="MENU logo" width="150" height="50" onClick="window.location.reload();"> &nbsp
        <a class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-user">&nbsp</i>test
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        
            <a href="ucet.php">Môj účet</a>
            <a href="logout.php">Odhlásiť sa</a>
        
        </div>
        <div class="header-right" id="myTopnav">
            <a class="active" href="/welcome.php">Úvodné menu</a>
            <a href="/online.php">Online hodiny</a>
            <a href="/du.php">Domáce úlohy</a>
            <a href="webcentrum/znamky">Známky</a>
            <a href="/rozvrh.php">Rozvrh hodín</a>
            <a href="/ospravedlnenky.php">Ospravedlnenky</a>
            <a href="/ucenie.php">Učebný materiál</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.classList.contains("topnav")) {
            x.classList.remove('topnav');
            x.classList.add('responsive');
        } else {
            x.classList.add('topnav');
            x.classList.remove('responsive');
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps little by little.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I hide the button in "pc mode"?